# how to show loading by html img element load remote src

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently when I open a page it shows a blank then the picture slowly shows up i want this kind of loading a remote picture to display a state with a fixed height use jquery code
[image][image][image]

Comment: I do it this way，$('.async').on('load',function () {
        $(this).unbind('load');
        this.src = $(this).attr('data-img-url');
    });

Answer (score 1):

from you question I think you want to use loader while loading the images.
you can use css code to generate loader

```
<div class="loader"></div>

.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

than you can use class name in jquery to hide or show the loader at button click or page load

for hide loader

```
$('.loader').hide();
```

for show loader

```
$('.loader').show();
```